# Tinymce inline editor won't show the menu or toolbar inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I tried to use tinymce inline mode with bootstrap inside a modal.
The problem I had was, the toolbar won't be shown.

Here is a link to the jsfiddle example
https://jsfiddle.net/jsty5047/

So I tried increasing the z-index of toolbar and it showed it.
But it was not clickable.

I was able to show toolbar by using this css,

```
.tox-tinymce-inline {
    z-index: 1600 !important;
}
```

Please help me find a solution to this. I am stuck at the moment.
thank you!

Comment: Where is toolbar? I can't see any element with class `tox-tinymce-inline` in your `html`.

Comment: It is actually a class provided by tinymce core code. It is generated by it

Comment: Apparently when I removed the tab-index= -1 in modal it works.. I have no idea how though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens due to the tabindex="-1" in the modal div. I'm not sure of the reason for this. But when I removed it, it started working properly. I added it in the jsFiddle link above as well.

I also had to add the following css, otherwise the toolbar is not visible.

```
.tox-tinymce-inline {
    z-index: 1600 !important;
}
```